# Local variable referenced before assignment in decorated method

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, python-decorators

I'm creating a decorator that would allow me to do stuff like:

```
@cooldownf(lambda self, **eargs: 30 - self.level)
def method(self, **eargs):
    ...
```

Which would simply decorate the method so that it has a cooldown.
This all worked just fine and the method can now be executed every `30 - self.level` seconds.

However, I wanted to add a message that would be displayed if the method is still on cooldown.
I added a `message` parameter for the `cooldownf` decorator, but then I got an error `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'message' referenced before assignment` from the line `ìf message:` in my decorator's code:

```
def cooldownf(fn, message=None):
    """Decorates a method to have a dynamic cooldown.

    Decorator function for easily adding cooldown as a dynamic time
    (function) into skill's methods. The function gets called when the
    cooldown is needed, and the skill is passed to the function.

    Args:
        fn: Function to determine the cooldown of the method
        message: Optional message sent if there's still cooldown left

    Returns:
        Decorated method with a dynamic cooldown
    """

    # Create a decorator using the function and message provided
    def method_decorator(method):

        # Create a wrapper method
        @wraps(method, assigned=WRAPPER_ASSIGNMENTS+('__dict__',), updated=())
        def method_wrapper(self, **eargs):

            # If the method's cooldown is over
            if method_wrapper.cooldown.remaining <= 0:

                # Restart the cooldown
                method_wrapper.cooldown.start(1, fn(self, **eargs))

                # And call the function
                return method(self, **eargs)

            # If there was cooldown remaining and a message is provided
            if message:

                # Format the provided message
                message = message.format(
                    name=self.name,
                    cd=method_wrapper.cooldown.remaining,
                    max_cd=method_wrapper.cooldown.limit
                )

                # Send it to the player
                SayText2(message=message).send(eargs['player'].index)

                # And exit with code 3
                return 3

        # Create the cooldown object for the wrapper
        method_wrapper.cooldown = TickRepeat(lambda: None)

        # And return the wrapper
        return method_wrapper

    # Return the decorator
    return method_decorator
```

What's causing this?
I can print `message` just fine inside of `cooldownf` or `method_decorator`, but adding a print into the `method_wrapper` will cause the error to raise.
That's exact code and I can't replicate it in [IDLE](https://docs.python.org/3/library/idle.html) with functions, does it have something to do with me using **methods** in particular?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are *assigning* to `message` in the innermost function:

```
message = message.format(
    name=self.name,
    cd=method_wrapper.cooldown.remaining,
    max_cd=method_wrapper.cooldown.limit
)
```

That assignment makes it a local variable, but you cannot make that assignment without first accessing `message`. You cannot do that with a local.

Since you don't want to modify the closed-over argument, you want to use a *new* local name here:

```
formatted_message = message.format(
    name=self.name,
    cd=method_wrapper.cooldown.remaining,
    max_cd=method_wrapper.cooldown.limit
)
SayText2(message=formatted_message).send(eargs['player'].index)
```

Comment: Is there anything you don't know? No but seriously, thanks :) I'm still not sure how it happens (message is defined in the `cooldownf`'s parameters?), but at least I know why :) Your solution worked

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen: Python defines what scope a name belongs to by *binding*; if you assign to a name, or import a name or create a function or a class with a given name, then you are binding that name in that scope. If you don't assign, then Python has to find the name in a parent scope; either a global or a built-in, or from an enclosing scope.

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen: if you don't assign to `message`, it is not a local, so Python will look for it in the enclosing scope and find it there. If you do assign to it it is a local and outer scopes are not consulted. That is, until you tell Python to do so anyway with the  `global` or `nonlocal` statements. But then you would also *set* that `message` variable to the output of the `message.format()` operation.

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen: the solution then is to use a different local name to hold the formatted version of the message, and leave `message` to be pulled in from the parent scope, leaving it unaltered.

Comment: Thank you very much @MartijnPieters, you've been much of help :) !